# Can we have an RSS feed of the site?

Tags: support, tagging

I was wondering, can we add a feature of having RSS feeds? It will be great if we can get RSS by Tag.

Answer (score 1):

The following RSS feeds are available on the site.

- Most recent active questions, from the [home page](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com)
- Most recent active questions for a tag, from any tag page ([single tag example](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq), [multi tag example](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/workflow+deployment))

Answer (score 1):

Short but simple: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/feeds

It seems to run a bit behind though as it is probably cached. I got this question in Google Reader about 30 minutes late.